# How to see which test data is classified incorrectly

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, classification, imdb

The accuracy at the output is not 100%, hence there are texts that are classified by the network incorrectly. How can I look at these texts after the network?

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation,Dropout
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras import optimizers
from keras.layers import Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D

np.random.seed(42)

max_features = 10000
maxlen = 400
batch_size = 64
embedding_dims = 200
filters = 150
kernel_size = 5
hidden_dims = 50
epochs =5

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=1000)

print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
print(x_train[0])
print(y_train[0])
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=1000)
x_train = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(x_train, mode='binary')
x_test = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(x_test, mode='binary')
print(x_train[0])

num_classes = 2
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(512,input_dim = 1000,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(num_classes,activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()



opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.1, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

clf = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1)
print("Accuracy: ", score[1])
```

I tried this code, but got an error

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)

# bolean mask
mask = y_pred != y_test

# print rows that was classified incorrectly    
print(x_test[mask])
```

> print(x_test[mask]) IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed
>   array along dimension 1; dimension is 1000 but corresponding boolean
>   dimension is 2

Answer (score 0):

I changed your complete code so that it runs through with only one class (since we are studying a binary problem) and you can study the wrongly classified samples. The result proves that you are using a completly unsuitable model for your task.

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation,Dropout
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras import optimizers
from keras.layers import Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)

max_features = 10000
maxlen = 400
batch_size = 64
embedding_dims = 200
filters = 150
kernel_size = 5
hidden_dims = 50
epochs =5

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=1000)

print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
print(x_train[0])
print(y_train[0])
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=1000)
x_train = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(x_train, mode='binary')
x_test = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(x_test, mode='binary')
print(x_train[0])

num_classes = 1
#y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
#y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(512,input_dim = 1000,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(num_classes,activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()



opt = optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

clf = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1)
print("Accuracy: ", score[1])

y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
df_test_pred = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x_test), pd.DataFrame(y_test, columns= ['test']), pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns= ['pred'])], axis=1)

df_wrong= df_test_pred[df_test_pred['test'] != df_test_pred['pred']]
```

Comment: Error: ValueError: Must pass 2-d input

Comment: name 'y_true' is not defined

Comment: Can u help me plz?

Comment: my y_true is your y_test

Comment: So? how i can fix this?

Comment: can you post your data? make sure y_test and y_pred are 1d

Comment: My data it's matrix [[0. 1. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 1. ... 1. 0. 1.]

Comment: I meant y_test and y_pred, pls show these vectors. They need to be 1d

Comment: Y_pred = [[0.502208   0.4944316 ]
 [0.49238363 0.5074519 ]
 [0.5011785  0.49540251]
 ...
 [0.5063672  0.48914844]
 [0.5059144  0.48959407]
 [0.5018937  0.4947943 ]]
Y_test = [[1. 0.]
 [0. 1.]
 [0. 1.]
 ...
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]
 [1. 0.]]

Comment: Since you're dealing with a binary problem I would suggest you to use only one class (either it's in the class or not), to do this, change the following lines to `num_classes = 1
#y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
#y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)` so just don't use the categorical transformation. If you apply my code then, you see which ones you missed.

Comment: Now  i got this error: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Comment: could not broadcast input array from shape (25000,1) into shape (25000)

Comment: see my edited post above, this is the solution to the problem to had but not to classifying your dataset.

Comment: accuracy all time 50%, and how i can see incorrectly reviews in text form?

Comment: for higher accuracy you shouldn't limit your optimizer in the way you did!!! just use 'opt = optimizers.Adam()' which pushed my accuracy to 84%. All the data you have is just in numeric form, how do you expect to extract a text form?